# What indexes will I need to make on this SQL Server table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, indexing

I have the following sql query for a SQL Server 2008 db.

```
SELECT TOP(@NumberOfStreetResults) LocationType, LocationId, Name
FROM [dbo].[LocationNames] 
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, @SearchQuery)
    AND LocationType = 7
```

Notice how I'm using the `CONTAINS` keyword? I have an *FTS* on the `Name` field.

I'm not sure what index(s) I need to manually add to the table because this query is very common in our system.

Do I need to just add an index against `LocationType`?

### Update

Here's the query graphs...

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would analyze the query (via the Database Engine Tuning Advisor) to see if further indexes would increase the performance.

Comment: You might appreciate the website [Use the Index, Luke!](http://use-the-index-luke.com/)--it aims to be a guide to database performance for developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF your LocationType is highly selective then my suggestion is to create a covered index on that table with key as LocationType and add LocationId in your include column list

Answer (score 0):

Simply an index is a temporary table in SQL which keeps a copy of indexed column sorted. When a new row is inserted SQL puts a new record in temp table at the correct place so an index has the following results:

**A) Advantages:**

1) Increase in search speed because the table is sorted in a temp table based on indexed field(s)

**B) Disadvantages:**

1) Slow down CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) because same actions should be done on temp tables if needed.

2) DataBase size increases because of using temp tables.

**Conclusion:**

Use indexing on fields which you frequently refer to them as the search criteria (WHERE)

Comment: That'll work for the general case; what about this particular instance?

Comment: too general for an answer. The question is very specific and requires a very specific answer.

Comment: Agreed - that's a generic answer about **Index's** .. which I sorta know about. Good try mate and welcome to StackOverflow. Can you try and be more sepcific to my question though?

Comment: I just tried to help clarify the trade-offs. So an answer to his question "Do i need to just add an index against LocationType?" depends on how much he write this query "WHERE LocationType..." as I mentioned. As a specific answer (guess it's a smal-medium project) use indexing on "LocationType" or any fileld you are doubtful about.